# How to use laravel echo with react js?

Tags: reactjs, pusher, laravel-echo

i am creating a chatting application with pusher in laravel and using react j s for front-end.now when i use Echo.channel in react js it shows channel is not defined.how to solve this problem or any alternative way to do this???

this is in my App.js:

> import Echo from 'laravel-echo'
>
> window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');
>
> window.Echo = new Echo({
>       broadcaster: 'pusher',
>       key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
>       cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
>       forceTLS: true });

and this is in my react js chatUi :

> listen = () => {
>
> ```
>     window.Echo.channel('my_channel');
>     channel.listen('FormSubmitted', function (data) {
>         alert(JSON.stringify(data));
>     });
>
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue... In my case, I have a separate js file for my react application (`resources/js/react.js`) in which I am not requiring the bootstrap.js.  So, I just copied the import echo into my react.js file.  My entire `resources/js/react.js` file is below.

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo'

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    encrypted: true
});

import Component from './react/index';
```

Remember to re-compile by running `npm run dev`

Answer (score 0):

I did this from within the constructor() of the React.Component so that I could call a componenent method (pullTexts) on websocket update; it fires when the TwilioTextCreated event fires:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    ...

    window.Echo.channel("twiliotexts")
    .listen('TwilioTextCreated', (e) => {
        this.pullTexts();
        console.log("within reactjs component - twilio text created");
    });
}
```

And in my Event:

```
class TwilioTextCreated implements ShouldBroadcastNow
{
    ...

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('twiliotexts');
    }

}
```